# Need an AVERAGE from a MULTIPLE CRITERIA VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not an Excel expert. I've tried to achieve something that for me seems simple at the beginning but than I've spend a few hours in searching and trying different solutions but couldn't find something that fits my problem. I hope some of you guys will find a solution for me?

This is my problem:
The sample table:

```
A    B    C    D    E    F
1st  A    ?    ?    ?    12.58%
1st  B    ?    ?    ?    10.25%
1st  A    ?    ?    ?    8.56%
2nd  A    ?    ?    ?    10.23%
2nd  B    ?    ?    ?    15.26%
etc.
```

What I want to achieve is to find the AVERAGE percent for all 1st (column A) and A's (column B) if possible. The percentage is calculated in column F and the other columns contain other number irrelevant to the problem.

I've tried some VLOOKUP and INDEX&MATCH but with no success.
I hope someone here can help me.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: @pnuts - Exactly like that, I just used sample numbers to simplify the problem. Those percentage numbers are actual yield used out of some material. I'm trying to calculate the average yield for particular product produced at the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try =AVERAGEIFS(F2:F6,A2:A6,"1st",B2:B6,"A")

Comment: I just found out about the AVERAGEIFS with multiple criteria and I did it, was just posting my own answer but you was faster. Thanks anyway